# Export a joined view

Tags: data-view-web-part, export, joined-view

I have created a joined view (with a Data View Web Part in SharePoint Designer), how can I export it (ideally to Excel)?

Comment: Is JavaScript/jQuery a credible option to use for your solution?

Comment: Well, tell me more! I need this to work in IE 8, so no html5 allowed. And we are talking about hundreds of list items.

Comment: Check this [Export Data View to excel in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/09/22/export-data-view-to-excel-in-sharepoint-2016-2013/)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't way for that to directly export to Excel.  However, as iOnline247 mentioned, you can use jQuery to convert the HTML table on the page to CSV.  Then you can save that and open it with Excel: http://www.kunalbabre.com/projects/table2CSV.php

Comment: I've used that library many times, works well.

Comment: Interesting... Does this work when the table contains other tables (which would obviously be the case with joined views)? Also, it doesn't address the save step.

Comment: link not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

John Chapman is spot on with deciphering my comment.  With a php solution, you'd have to have those bits on the server for it to work.  I'm more familiar with datatables and the export options that exist with this library.

[Datatables TableTools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/)

If I remember correctly, we've done some very funky reporting --> export using this library.  I'll ping Mark Rackley and get a definitive answer on the nested table question.

Comment: thx Matt. It seems that the TableTools rely on Flash, like what I have on my user toolkit. Same concern, does it work with multiple layers of tables, not just a datagrid?

Comment: Mark will have a definitive answer.  He'll be able to set this straight.  It's been a while since I've worked with the codebase on that project.  I thought we did though.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to:

1. Create and Web Query in Excel ([How to create a Web Query in Excel](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-import-online-data-into-excel-2010-with-a-w.html)),
2. save the query (`*.iqy`),
3. uploaded the web query file to the site
4. and just added "Export to Excel" linked to the query file.