# Export out data view list to Excel

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have a data view list made using a linked data source of several SP lists. I tried to make it so that the data view list can be exported out as Excel, just like SP list. Is this possible?

I tried to follow the solution in here - [Export a joined view](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35341/export-a-joined-view) but somehow it didn't work for me. Any other Javascript plugin that i can use to make this work? Or is there any way i can enable export function on data view using Sharepoint designer?

Thanks

Comment: I ended up following this tutorial to create something for my Data view. https://ameyakawale.wordpress.com/2011/08/04/exporting-dataview-webpart-data-into-excel-using-javascript/

Comment: @RamanaViswanadha thanks. I did followed that too, but didn't work with me. Not sure if i got the table ID right. Which one is the table ID that the code refers too? Is it the web part ID?

Comment: There should be an attribute called just "id" on the html tag of your table. But what I ended up doing was exporting my webpart, and then edited the exported file in notepad to add an Id attribute that i can use. After which i uploaded it back onto sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

xlsx.js is a nice plugin for JavaScript to Excel.
[xlsx export demo](http://sheetjs.com/demos/table.html)

allows you to make custom Excel files from custom data.

Source files and documentation: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx